# Include not finding module RubyMotion

Tags: rubymotion

Are mixins allowed in RubyMotion? I have a directory with two files. One is a class, the other a module. When I include the module (mixin) in my class, I get a not found error. Everything under app is automatically required in RM right?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Found it! http://dylanmarkow.com/blog/2012/05/06/load-order-with-rubymotion/

Comment: I think the solution in that article might cause problems if you're using Bundler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Bundler, so I ended up putting something like this in the `Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|` block:

```
app_files = app.files.reverse.pop
app.files << Dir.glob(File.join(app.project_dir, 'lib/**/*.rb')) << app_files
```

There is definitely a better way to do this.