# RubyMotion require method alternative

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have same methods in Controllers for deleting/showing CoreData objects. I've decided to put into its own Module. But found out that `require` is not supported by RubyMotion.

How should I go about including Helpers module I have to my Controllers? I've tried `load`,`include`,`require_realtive` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` definitely works.  If you get errors when using `include`, you have a load order issue.  There are 2 different options to fix that, depending on if you are using bundler, or not.  Those 2 options are detailed on this similar question:

[Include not finding module RubyMotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060309/include-not-finding-module-rubymotion)